# Github pages 404 File not found

Tags: html, css, git, github, github-pages

I'm new to Github pages and Sass and am trying to deploy my first site. However, I get a 404 error when opening my site https://manayam.github.io/portfolio/ but have not been able to figure out why.

It looks like my settings are configured correctly since I get the checkmark saying my site is published.

Before this, I had a friend help me and he deleted my master branch since I couldn't figure out how to update my repo with both branches, if that's relevant to the current problem. Although I looked up it is not good practice, I force pushed to be able to update the repo since it was rejecting my pushes. Since then, I have been able to update my repo but now the site receives the 404 error.

The repo is at https://github.com/manayam/portfolio. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't upload an index page to your root, and GitHub Pages doesn't allow directory listings. If you actually go to the `dist` subdirectory where there is an index page (https://manayam.github.io/portfolio/dist/), it works fine.

Comment: Oh well now I feel silly. However, is there a way that I can have the URL without the subdirectory in there? Otherwise, I'll just use this link to apply to things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just upload your files in the repository root instead of in dist/ then.